# how to set the alarm manager for background task to get the current position

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am doing an app using location and gecoder ,hence i have to implement alarm manager to get the current position for every 5min,hence i have done codings for getting the current position, hence I have to repeat it every 5min to the position please help me,thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is or why you think you need to use `AlarmManager` to update every 5 minutes. Why don't you just use the `LocationManager` `requestLocationUpdates(...)` methods providing a `LocationListener` and an update interval of 5 minutes?

Comment: i am getting the current location but i have to view the current location every 5min

Comment: Yes, and the `LocationListener` will be called every 5 minutes and will be able to update the location in the view.

Comment: thanks for your reply please give codings please

Comment: pleas help me how to show the current location for every 5min

Comment: It's all in the training section on the Android dev site. http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html take special note of the section "Receiving Location Updates" which explains requesting periodic updates and using a `LocationListener`.